# How do I clear/reset an array inside state in React (JSX)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, jsx

I am trying to make a simple page with React and JSX that will generate a couple of input fields which can be erased by clicking a button.

I am currently storing an empty array within the Page's state, which gets updated by the addItems function.

For some reason, I am not able to clear the array with my clear function. I understand that `setState` is asynchronous, but my array never gets updated and never disappears.

```
"use strict";

function Node(props) {
    return(<div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="input here"></input>
    </div>);
}

class Page extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            arr: [],
            thresh: 5,
            del: "Delete",
        };
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
        this.clear = this.clear.bind(this);
    }

    addItem = (index, array) => {
        if (index == this.state.thresh) {
            this.setState((state, props) => ({
                arr: array,
            }));
            return;
        }
        index++;
        array.push(<Node key={index} />);
        this.addItem(index, array);
    };

    clear = newArr => {
        this.setState({
            arr: newArr,
        }, () => { console.log(this.state.arr) });
    };

    render() {
        return(<div id="wrapper onClick={() => {this.addItem(0,[])}}>
        <div id="fields">
        {this.state.arr}
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => {this.clear([])}}>{this.state.del}</button>
        </div>
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I am expecting that when I hit the delete button the array will be overwritten with an empty array but this does not happen. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: It is the clear function executed when you click the button?

Comment: "...but this does not happen" What evidence do you have that this isn't working the way it should? As far as I can tell, your `clear()` function looks correct. On the other hand, your `addItem()` function looks strange, especially because you are pushing to an array **after** you call `setState()`. I suggest that you install the React Developer Tools addon for your browser. This will allow you to directly inspect your component's state to see if it is working correctly. This is more reliable than `console.log()`.

Comment: @JosepVidal yes the function executes.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the callback function prints an array with elements inside of it. In regards to addItem, I forgot to include a line which I've just added.

Answer (score 1):

clear function looks alright, altho when i tried to run your code, it popped up multiple errors and a typo. 
Also addItem method looks weird to me... you are not pushing nodes into state.arr instead your are pushing it into empty array all the time.

here i tried to clean up code a bit, and even though functionality might not be what you want to have, it proves the concept that cleanup is the first thing you need to do :)

in snippet below clear function works fine and it's not modified.

```
function Node(props) {
    return(<div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="input here"></input>
    </div>);
}

class Page extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            arr: [],
            thresh: 5,
            del: "Delete",
        };
        this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
        this.clear = this.clear.bind(this);
    }

    addItem(index, array) {

        var newArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.arr))
        newArr.push(<Node />)
            this.setState({
              arr: newArr
            });
    }

    clear(newArr) {
        this.setState({
            arr: newArr,
        }, () => { console.log(this.state.arr) });
    }

    render() {
        return(<div>
        <div id="wrapper" onClick={() => {this.addItem(0,[1])}}>asdasd</div>
          <div id="fields"> {this.state.arr} </div>
          <button onClick={() => {this.clear([])}}>{this.state.del}</button>
        </div>)
    }


}
ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Try building / adding your logic on top of code here and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your clear method should look like this:

```
clear = () => {
        this.setState({
            arr: [],
        });
    };
```

your click handler in button :

```
<button onClick={this.clear}>{this.state.del}</button>
```

and if you use arrow functions you don't have to bind them in constructor, you can remove bind's

Comment: For some reason this still doesn't seem to fix the issue. The console.log() in the callback function prints five elements that are still in the array.

Comment: add cnsole.log in render, not as a callback of setstate

Answer (score 0):

`

```
clear = () => {
        this.setState({
            arr: [],
        }, () => { console.log(this.state.arr) });
        setTimeout(() => { console.log("o/p", this.state.arr); }, 3000);
    };
```

`
It will work try to put timer function. it works Acyncronasly.

Comment: You shouldn't need the timeout. The call back to `this.setState()` will be called after the state has been modified.

Answer (score 0):

I'm noticing quite a few problems here but one thing i see is your delete button is wrapped in the container that adds. so every time you click delete, it also will add to the array.

on another note though, this code doesn't seem functional. The way its written looks like it will never add anything to the state array so i'm not sure how you are seeing anything other than an empty array.

I believe you're trying to accomplish something like this:

```
function Node(props) {
    return (<div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="input here"></input>
    </div>);
}

export default class ClearTest extends React.Component<any, any> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            arr: [<Node key={1} />],
            thresh: 5
        };
    }

    addItem = () => {
        const { arr, thresh } = this.state;
        if (arr.length < thresh)
        this.setState({ arr: [...(arr), <Node key={arr.length + 1} />] })
    };

    clear = () => {
        this.setState({ arr: [] }, () => { console.log(this.state.arr) });
    };

    public render() {
        return (
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="fields">
                    {this.state.arr}
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.clear}>Delete</button>
                <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

this will move the add to a button and allow up  to 5 inputs to be added. Clicking delete will remove them all.

Comment: Thank you this was my problem! I just needed it to not fill up every time after by calling the addItems function

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset it using a custom reset function:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const getDefaultState = () => ({
  myArray: [],
});

class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { ...getDefaultState() };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ myArray: [1, 2, 3] })
  }

  resetState = () => {
    this.setState({ ...getDefaultState() });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.resetState}>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.myArray)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```